# Checking for palindrome using recursion in PYTHON

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

I am checking if a word is a palindrome, and I cant seem to get my code to respond. I feel like its pretty sound, but apparently I'm missing something. can someone point out what that may be?

```
def reverse(usrWrd, index):   
    newWord = ""  

    if index == len(usrWrd):
        return newWord
    else:
      newWord += usrWrd[index]
      return reverse(usrWrd, index + 1)

def main(): 
    usrWrd = input("please enter a word to check for palindrome-ness:")

    result = reverse(usrWrd, 0)
    if result == usrWrd:
        print("That word is a palindrome")
    else:
        print("Sorry,",usrWrd,  "is NOT a palindrome")

main()
```

Comment: You are setting `newWord` to blank string every time in `reverse()`

Comment: Also call `reverse` with `len(usrWrd) - 1` instead of `0`

Comment: pythonic way 
`s == s[::-1]` returns True if s is palidrome string and False otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Correct approach to your solution
def reverse(usrWrd, index, newWord):
    if index < 0:
        return newWord
    else:
      newWord += usrWrd[index]
      return reverse(usrWrd, index - 1, newWord)

def main():
    newWord = ""
    usrWrd = input("please enter a word to check for palindrome-ness:")
    result = reverse(usrWrd, len(usrWrd) - 1, newWord)

    if result == usrWrd:
        print("That word is a palindrome")
    else:
        print("Sorry,",usrWrd,  "is NOT a palindrome")
```

#############################################################

```
# Alternate approach
def isPalindrome(usrWord):
    sLen = len(usrWord)
    if sLen <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        if usrWord[0] != usrWord[sLen-1]:
            return False
        else:
            return isPalindrome(usrWord[1:sLen-1])

def main():
    newWord = ""
    usrWrd = input("please enter a word to check for palindrome-ness:")
    result = isPalindrome(usrWrd)

    if result:
        print("That word is a palindrome")
    else:
        print("Sorry,",usrWrd,  "is NOT a palindrome")
```

#############################################################

```
# Pythonic way as suggested by 'Yaman Jain'
if usrWord == usrWord[::-1]:
    return True # Palindrome
else:
    return False # Not Palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrome(s):
   length = len(s);
   if length <= 1:
       return True
   if s[0] != s[length-1]:
       return False
   return isPalindrome(s[1:length-1])
```

Or for those who like even more terse code:

```
def isPalindrome(s):
   return (len(s) <= 1) or ((s[0] == s[-1]) and isPalindrome(s[1:-1]))
```

Comment: you can just use `-1` in place of `length - 1`

Comment: True. But I assume since the op is new at programming, I intentionally used a more verbose style for readability.

Comment: Meh..makes it look like golang

Comment: How you like me now?

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(usrWrd, index):
    newWord = ""                     # This is a local

    if index == len(usrWrd):
        return newWord               # It will always be empty string here

    else:
        newWord += usrWrd[index]
        return reverse(usrWrd, index + 1)
```

I'm not sure why you think you need `newWord` at all. You should just compare the first and last letters are equal, and then use your recursive function to check the remaining substring is also a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned local variable is the issue, may be u can send the local variable along. Typical tail recursion implementation

```
def reverse(usrWrd, index, newWord=''):

    if index == len(usrWrd):
        return newWord       
    else:
        newWord += usrWrd[index]
        return reverse(usrWrd, index + 1, newWord)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    usrWrd = input("please enter a word to check for palindrome-ness:")

    result=reversed(usrWrd)

    if list(result) == list(usrWrd):
        print("That word is a palindrome")
    else:
        print("Word is NOT a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rec_palindrome(S, n):
    if not S:
        return False
    if n == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return S[n] == S[(len(S)-1) - n] and rec_palindrome(S, n - 1)
```

Please suggest improvements if any

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        print("yes it is")
        return True
    else:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
```

This is another solution you might want to check!

Answer (score 0):

```
    string=string.lower()
    if(len(string)<2):
       return True 
    elif(string[0]!=string[-1]):
       return False
    else:
       return string[1:-1]
palin=is_palindrome("Abbacus")
if(palin):
  print("The string is palindrome")
else:
  print("The string is not Palindrome")
```

Comment: Where you can also check for case insensitive strings whether there are palindrome or not.